# Alternatives to PIL/Pillow for overlaying an image with text

Tags: python, image-manipulation, python-imaging-library

Do any Python alternatives exist for overlaying an image with text?  I tried with PIL/Pillow, but the output is really grainy and artifacted.

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw

img = Image.open("image.jpg")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype("Comic Sans MS.ttf", 24)
draw.text((150, 20),"Sample Text",(170,14,179), font=font)
img.save('sample-out123.jpg')
```

and the output:

[image]

You can see artifacting around the text as well as a light purple glow.

Comment: There's no reason it should be grainy and artifacted. Maybe you should show some code and ask if there's something wrong with it, along with an example image exhibiting the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what this artifacting you're claiming is. Have you tried outputting to a lossless format such as PNG?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known problem with JPEG images](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~jakulin/jpeg/artifacts.htm).

Try changing the image quality:

```
img.save('sample-out123.jpg', quality=95)
```

Or, save as a PNG.

```
img.save('sample-out123.png')
```

Comment: Just a side note that, according to PIL's manual (http://effbot.org/imagingbook/format-jpeg.htm) `values above 95 should be avoided` for quality. (same thing mentioned in Pillow's docs http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html#jpeg)